# How to share an ArcGIS Online Operations Dashboard with someone outside the organization?

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I am attempting to share an operation dashboard publicly, but when other ArcGIS Online users attempt to view it, they receive an error message that they are not part of the organization.
[image]

Here is the organization security (anonymous access allowed):
[image]

And here is a screenshot of the Share Dialog when sharing the operations dashboard:
[image]

How does an ArcGIS Online user, who is not a member of an organization, authenticate with the organization in order to view the dashboard?

Comment: Are the services used within the dashboard shared publicly?

Comment: Also make sure you arent giving them a URL like:  https://MYORG.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/09cf9905348a3a3f718451b24da33  - instead give them https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/09cf9895348a3a3f718451b24da33